# Reverting with GS026 error for isValidSignature(messageHash, signature)

Tags: safe-core

I am trying to signMessage with the EOA owner of the safe wallet.

```
const message = "hello"
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
const signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.hexlify(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message)))
```

And using isValidSignature to verify the message.

```
await smartWalletContract.isValidSignature(ethers.hashMessage(message), signature);
```

But validation reverts with this error

```
'execution reverted: "GS026" (action="call", data="0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054753303236000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", reason="GS026", transaction={ "data": "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", "to": "0x82a6b139cE50B5e7974cDe1068343f43B0CA1D48" }, invocation=null, revert={ "args": [ "GS026" ], "name": "Error", "signature": "Error(string)" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.11.1)'
```

**I am on `Mumbai` Network**

Safe Address: `0x82a6b139cE50B5e7974cDe1068343f43B0CA1D48`

EOA owner signing the message: `0x1dE58d46D05a379e020b1cBED0Db98a2F55831B2`

Checked using the `getOwners` on safe address, safe owner: `0x1dE58d46D05a379e020b1cBED0Db98a2F55831B2`

I ensured that the owner is right, so **`GS026: Invalid owner provided`** error is not making sense, please help me with this issue.

Let me know if I am doing something wrong with the message to sign.

Answer (score 0):

It might appear illogical at first, but this error does make sense: contracts check signatures and derives an EOA that it compares to the list of owners. If the signature is wrongly formatted, the contract will consider it's a different address trying to interact with the safe, and then throw this error - instead of indicating that the signature is wrongly formatted.

To fix your implementation, you can try to use [this method](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/6bb692d64ab0bba4c1d40706e1458ad0ab0a6d2b/packages/protocol-kit/src/Safe.ts#L529) from Safe{Core} SDK protocol kit instead of `ethers.hexlify(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message))`

You can also try following [this tutorial](https://docs.safe.global/sdk-protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages#ecdsa-signatures) from the protocol kit documentation dedicated to signing ECDSA messages.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis